# Dataframe multiple condition

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following table

```
    Wh    Cost  Capacity
 0  NaN   0.0      NaN
 1  5.0  2350.0    500.0
 2  4.0  2080.0    0.0
 3  7.0  2890.0    500.0
```

I want to select the WH with the least cost  and where the capacity not equal 0
the output will be 5.0

Im not sure how to get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the dataframe based on `capacity not equal to zero` and then find the `min of the resulted dataframe` and check the min cost and compare it with `Cost column`. Refer the below solution:

```
filteredDf = df[df['Cost']==df[(df['Capacity']!=0)&(df['Cost']!=0)]['Cost'].min()]
```

Output:

```
    Wh    Cost  Capacity
0  5.0  2350.0     500.0
```

Comment: output:              Wh  Cost  Capacity
                   0    NaN   0.0       NaN
 how do i exclude the NaN

Comment: @BrianA.Dorantes You add conditions as per your requirement and enhance it further

Comment: @BrianA.Dorantes in order to replace NaN you can use fillna and if you need to drop the records you can use dropna as well. You can also add filter condition of you don't wish to replace or remove the records.

Comment: @BrianA.Dorantes if this helps you with the solution then could you please mark it as answer :-)

Comment: Using df[df['Cost'] == df[(df['Capacity'] != 0) & (df['Cost'] != 0)]['Cost'].min()], gives me the row where the cost is minum and capacity not equal 0, if I want to select the wh of that row and get the index of that wh ,how it will be?

Answer (score 0):

Using
`df[df['Cost'] == df[(df['Capacity'] != 0) & (df['Cost'] != 0)]['Cost'].min()]`

This gives me the result

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Vaibhav answer, you can add Wh column at the end to get precise answer.

```
filteredDf = df[df['Cost']==df[(df['Capacity']!=0)&(df['Cost']!=0)]['Cost'].min()].Wh
```